# Toggle auto-keyframing in the 2D animation workspace

Tags: animation, 2d

would be grateful for anyone who could point out the button or shortcut key to disable/toggle auto-keyframing in the new Blender 2D workspace.

I can't see the auto-keyframing button in the dope sheet or graph editor when I choose "2D Animation" for my initial file format.

Comment: Even in old versions of Blender I don't have an _Auto Keying_ button in the _Dopesheet Editor_ or the _Graph Editor_, it's always been in the _Timeline_ menu.

Comment: Correct, the blue/white dot to the left of the Play/Skip/Jump to keyframe buttons in the Timeline window is how you set auto-keying.